# How to find the name of changed file in Forms API

Tags: 7, forms

I've a file field attached to a node form. I want to know in the submit handler if the file has been replaced then I'll take some action.

For example I delete the previously uploaded file : abc.txt and then upload a new one "newdoc.txt" in place of it and "Submit".

I don't want to  load the node and read it's contents or use hook_presave and read the value using $node->original.

Comment: Do you mean incase of node edit ? Why you don't want to load the node and read it's contents or use hook_presave and read the value using $node->original ?

Comment: If those old values are already available in the $form_state then why query the database the long way. Can I get it from the $form or $form_state?

Comment: I believe if you do hook_form_alter and add extra submit handler.. In your submit handler $node is part of either $form or $form_state.. Did you verify that ?

Comment: Thanks you're right. There is 'node' in form_state which shows the old content. I was confused as dsm shows it as some recursion instead of the node content. But dsm($form_state['node']) shows fine.

Comment: Posted same few minutes back as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just verified it... Form submit handler does store old values and new values..

In $form you see old fid in #node property , In $form_state['values'] you see new fid that was uploaded...

[image]
[image]

By comparing above two in your submit handler you can take action..

```
function my_custom_submit_file_alter_detector($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form);
  dpm($form_state);
}
```

Comment: Where can I find current filename? Since in form_state['values']['file_fieldname'] it simply gives fid. And form_state arrays are unendingly long.

Comment: I've got this field: $form_state['complete form']['field_disavow_file']['und']['0']['#file']->filename  ... can I use it for the replaced filename?

Comment: Yes you can if that is what it is..

Comment: I mean will it work for all node forms? Is it the standard way?

Comment: Yes.. If you see for one content type for other too it's same.. Regarding 'standard way'.. I may prefer going to presave hook .. I believe it's opinion based..